# How to check if the both the columns in the dataframe has values using pandas

Tags: pandas

```
I have a df:
col1   col2   col3   col4    col5
bat    cell   val            val
cat    ribo   val    val
rat    dna    val            val
dog    rna    val    val     val
```

if i am comparing col4 and col5 i want to get the output as:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4    col5
dog    rna    val    val     val
```

bec col4 has value and col5 has value.

if i compare the col3 and col5 i should get the output as:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4    col5
bat    cell   val            val
rat    dna    val            val
dog    rna    val    val     val
```

but when i am using the following code:

```
dfn = df[df['col4'] != df['col5']]
```

not getting the correct df values.

and i want to add the output to the dataframe as:

```
col1   col2   col3   col5
dog    rna    val    val
```

Comment: Do you think `dfn = df[df['col4'] == df['col5']]` ? If `not getting the correct df values.` - Can you explain more?

Comment: `val` stands for same value at all the places or any value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a simple function for this to compare columns and rows which are empty:

## Method 1: using `Boolean indexing` with `notnull`

```
df.replace('', np.NaN, inplace=True)

def compare_cols(dataframe, column1, column2):
    return df[df[column1].notnull() & df[column2].notnull()]
```

---

```
print(compare_cols(df, 'col4', 'col5'))
print('\n')
print(compare_cols(df, 'col3', 'col5'))

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
3  dog  rna  val  val  val


  col1  col2 col3 col4 col5
0  bat  cell  val  NaN  val
2  rat   dna  val  NaN  val
3  dog   rna  val  val  val
```

---

**Edit** after Jezraels comment. We can use `dropna` with `subset` which gives the same output:

## Method 2: using `dropna`

```
def compare_cols2(dataframe, column1, column2):
    return df.dropna(subset=[column1, column2])
```

---

```
print(compare_cols2(df, 'col4', 'col5'))
print('\n')
print(compare_cols2(df, 'col3', 'col5'))

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
3  dog  rna  val  val  val


  col1  col2 col3 col4 col5
0  bat  cell  val  NaN  val
2  rat   dna  val  NaN  val
3  dog   rna  val  val  val
```

---

**Note** I replaced the whitespaces ('') with `NaN` so we can use `notnull()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #can you try below
    df1=df.loc[(df['col4'].notnull() & df['col5'].notnull()),:]]
    print(df1)
```